# Comparing String Arrays in C

Tags: c, string

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    char words[256];
    char filename[64];
    int count = 0;

    printf("Enter the file name: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);

    FILE *fileptr;
    fileptr = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(fileptr == NULL)
        printf("File not found!\n");

    while ((fscanf(fileptr, " %s ", words))> 0)
    {
        if (words==' ' || words == '\n')
        count++;
    }

    printf("%s contains %d words.\n", filename, count);

    return 0;

}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
         if (words==' ' || words == '\n')
                  ^
```

I don't get the error once I change, `words` to `*words` but that does not give me the correct results. I am trying count the number of words in a file.

Comment: strcmp() is what you shoul look for to compare char*

Comment: `words` is a string(or char array) and you are comparing it with a single char. Instead try strcmp(words," ") and strcmp(words,"\n");

Comment: not necessary compare because `%s` does not contain white spaces(e.g. `''` or `'\ n'`).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY then how I would I know if there's a new word? Isn't there spaces between words in a sentence?

Comment: try this `while ((fscanf(fileptr, "%s", words))> 0)
    {
        count++;
    }`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Genius!!! It works and I understand why it works. `fscanf` skips empty spaces. How do I choose you as best answer?

Comment: I was posted to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not necessary compare because `%s`(`words`) does not contain white spaces(e.g. `' '` or `'\n'`).

try this

```
while (fscanf(fileptr, "%s", words)> 0) {
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

words is char pointer while `' '` is char, *words equals to words[0]
usually we would define a new pointer as below

```
char *p =  words;
while(*p != '\0' )
{
  // using *p something you need to do 
  p++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `string` in C. Every string (/ literal) is an Array of chars. Use [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

Answer (score 0):

Take care that using the array name **words** by itself implies a pointer to the first element in the array. If what you need is to compare 2 strings in C then the **strcmp** is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare strings in `C`. You should compare them character by character using the standard library function `strcmp`. Here's its prototype contained in the `string.h` header.

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

The  `strcmp` function compares the two strings `s1` and `s2`.  It returns an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if `s1` is found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than `s2`.

The format string of fscanf `" %s "` (note the trailing and the leading space) will read and discard any number of whitespaces which it does anyway with the format string `"%s"`. This means no whitespaces will be written into the buffer `words` by `fscanf`. `fscanf` will write only non-whitespace characters in `words` and returns when it encounters a whitespace. So, to count the number of words, just increase the counter for each successful `fscanf` call.

Also, your program should check for possible buffer overflow in `scanf` and `fscanf` calls. If the input string is too big for the buffer, then this would cause undefined behaviour and even causing crash due to segfault. You can guard against it by changing the format string. `scanf("%63s", filename);` means scanf will read from `stdin` until it encounters a whitespace and write at most `63` non-whitespace characters in the buffer `filename` and then add a terminating null byte at the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    // assuming max word length is 256
    // +1 for the terminating null byte added by scanf
    char words[256 + 1]; 

    // assuming max file name length is 64
    // +1 for the terminating null byte 
    char filename[64 + 1]; 

    int count = 0;        // counter for number of words

    printf("Enter the file name: ");
    scanf("%64s", filename);

    FILE *fileptr;
    fileptr = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(fileptr == NULL)
        printf("File not found!\n");

    while((fscanf(fileptr, "%256s", words)) == 1)
        count++;

    printf("%s contains %d words.\n", filename, count);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I appreciate your effort on trying to help.